# Telerik GridViewComboBoxColumn can't differentate between ss and ß?

Tags: c#, telerik, datagridviewcombobox

I'm using a GridViewComboBoxColumn with AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend.
Recently I found out that the data in the dropdownbox of the autocompletebox has a problem (as has the editor).
The german double s and sharp s (aka ß) are seen as beeing identic in there.
And when a double s is typed in as for the german word strasse (street in english) it becomes straße instead inside the editor.

Is there any way to circumvent this so that these two "letters" are seen as being diffrent from each other?

Comment: for the record, in some instances, a double S and the ß are, in fact, interchangeable.

Comment: I know but in the cases where I need them (customer names in german language countries) they are not interchangeable.
(Also what I find quite unfunny is that when I type in strasse it is automatically changesd to straße instead despite both variants existing in the dropdownbox)

Comment: alright.  just making sure you were aware.  I'd almost say that there's some sort of validation happening that you need to change.  I will have to leave it to someone more knowledgeable than myself to say for sure though

Comment: Yepp I am aware (made sure 2 times that it is really what the customer wishes). My guess is more into the direction how telerik makes string comparisons there (there are issues when the german language collation from windows is used exactly THESE issues to be exact (for example the nonlegacy  sql server collations have these issues only legacy ones or _BIT collations dont have them) and tbh I am not sure where to start there best to replace the comparison methods or change what is used so that the problem is solved.